# How do I write to the console in java?

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line

I am working on a `command line` java program in `eclipse`. I used `System.out.println` to write to the console. It worked when I ran it with eclipse, but when I compiled it to a jar file, and ran it through cmd, it didn't write anything to the screen. Everything I looked up said to use `System.out.println` to write to command line. What should I do? Here is my code:

```
package cpac;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;




public class packfile {
    static double vernum = 1.1;
    public static void saveUrl(final String in2, final String urlString)
            throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        BufferedInputStream in = null;
        FileOutputStream fout = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(urlString).openStream());
            fout = new FileOutputStream(in2);

            final byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            int count;
            while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
                fout.write(data, 0, count);
            }
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
            if (fout != null) {
                fout.close();
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        int where = 0;
        System.out.println("CPac Version " + vernum);
        for (String s: args) {
            if (s.equals("update")) {
            java.io.File file = new java.io.File("cpac.jar");
            file.delete();
            saveUrl("cpac.jar", "http://example.com/package/cpac.jar");
            return;
            }



            if (s.equals("install")) {
                System.out.println("install");
                URL oracle = new URL("http://example.com/package/" + args[where + 1] +"/package.pac");
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

                String inputLine;
                String data = null;
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
                data = inputLine;
            }
                in.close();
                saveUrl(data, "http://example.com/package/" + args[where + 1] +"/" + data);
                System.out.println("Done!");

            }
            where = where + 1;
            }
        }
}
```

**EDIT:**
I just read something that says you can't run jar files by typing their name in cmd. Is there any way to not have to type a long command without needing an extra file?

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: Can you add the cmdline you start this with?

Comment: No output. I'm just typing "cpac.jar" in cmd.

Comment: If you package the jar file with a manifest, you can specify the classpath and main class in the manifest file.  Then your command would be `java -jar cpac.jar`

Comment: Thanks Ian. That is very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help to see what you entered on the command line.  Hopefully it looks something like this.

```
java -cp <filename.jar> cpac.packfile
```

Comment: I typed "cpac.jar" in cmd.

Comment: No, you should try it the way deanw is suggesting.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to reply.  Please check your path of the <filename.jar>.  If the jar is in another directory, then you must use the full path.

Answer (score 1):

"Worked in Eclipse" - an IDE is keeping you from understanding how things really work.

You don't run JAR files; you run the JRE and tell it to use a JAR file to find the main class that you specify in the META-INF/manifest.mf.

Are there no messages in the console?  Do you get no feedback?  If you [create the executable JAR properly](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html), your main class will run.  If your main class runs, it will write to the command shell when you print to the console.

Comment: I'm running it by typing the jar file name in cmd.